# Perl open(FH, "grep foo bar |") - close FH fails when grep returns nothing

Tags: perl, pipe

I'm opening a pipe to the **grep** command and reading the results line by line.  When done, I close the pipe.  If **grep** found anything, the **close()** completes normally.  If **grep** *didn't* find anything, the **close()** doesn't work.

Here's **foo** to demo the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use 5.010;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $search = shift // die "Usage: foo search_string";

open my $grep_h, "grep '$search' ./foo |"
  or die "open grep failed: $!";

while (defined (my $line = <$grep_h>)) {
    chomp $line;
    say "\t: $line";
}
close $grep_h or warn "Error closing grep pipe: $!";
```

Here I invoke **foo** to search itself for 'warn':

```
~/private/perl$ ./foo warn
    : use warnings;
    : close $grep_h or warn "Error closing grep pipe: $!";
```

Here I invoke **foo** to search itself for 'blarg':

```
~/private/perl$ ./foo blarg
Error closing grep pipe:  at ./foo line 16.
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`close($child)` sets `$?`. It returns false if `$?` is non-zero.

```
close($grep_h);
die "Can't close: $!\n" if $? == -1;
die "Child died from signal ".($? & 0x7F)."\n" if $? & 0x7F;
die "Child exited from error ".($? >> 8)."\n" if $? >> 8;
```

You'll get "Child exited from error 1" since `grep` returns an error when it finds no matches.

```
$ echo foo | grep foo
foo

$ echo $?    # Equivalent to Perl's $? >> 8
0

$ echo foo | grep bar

$ echo $?
1
```